# Как узнать, какие volumes хоста подключены к запущенному контейнеру?

Tags: docker

Есть запущенный контейнер, как узнать, какие каталоги хоста были примонтированы к нему?

Comment: `docker inspect CONTAINER_ID_HERE` вроде показывает `mounts` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
docker inspect --format {{.Mounts}} CONTAINER_NAME
```